# id_token doesn't contains the custom claims that I have defined (Adal.js + ADFS 2016)

Tags: openid, adfs, adal, adal.js

I'm doing an spike with ADAL.js (AngularJS) and OAuth2 (ADFS in Windows Server 2016)

I've enabled the Logging level 3, I'm sending the scope=openid, but, for some reason, my id_token doesn't contains all the custom Claims that I have defined.

Is this a problem with ADAL.js or ADFS 2016?

Thanks for your support.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Its unlikely to be AD FS if you followed instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/customize-id-token-ad-fs-2016 .

I suggest getting a Fiddler trace and see if the token issued by AD FS contains what you need. If you want a nice token decoder use https://www.authnauthz.com/oauthplayground/DecodeJWTToken or https://jwt.io/

Comment: I found the problem, ADAL.JS is using **response_mode=query**, that causes that the ADFS limits the amount of information because the URL restriction, if I change to **response_mode=form_post**, I got the complete **id_token** but, an Angular App can't receive a POST request... I'm trying to call the /adfs/userinfo but the ADFS Web Server doesn't have CORS enabled, so I can't...

Comment: I'm currently struggling with the same issue.
Maybe the following is a "solution": https://stackoverflow.com/a/43915687/885338

Microsofts decision in that case is just ridicoulus. It's my problem if I exceed the URL, not theirs...