# Getting Group Claims With ADFS 4.0 OAuth2 Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, adfs

I successfully set up an ADFS 4.0 instance (Windows Server 2016) which I intend to use to authenticate and authorize the users of a single-page application towards a WebApi.

I pretty much followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs .. which is modifying a sample that uses Azure Active Directory.

Now.. all seems to work fine, I can get a basic JWT token from the `/oauth2/authorize` endpoint:

```
{
  "aud": "d668d637-7fd4-45ef-9eab-46fee230dcbc",
  "iss": "https://fs.contoso.com/adfs",
  "iat": 1494341035,
  "exp": 1494344635,
  "auth_time": 1494341035,
  "nonce": "c91e3f78-c31a-402e-a685-8d1586915227",
  "sub": "Rl7sOj0nDbgh8BVWZegrkvgAKaB/SwNuEbmORcWcae4=",
  "upn": "john.doe@contoso.com",
  "unique_name": "CONTOSO\\JohnDoe"
}
```

The token from AzureAD contained more properties, particularly `family_name` and `given_name`. But I was also hoping to add explicit group claims to the token. I thought I should be able to make this happen by setting the *'Issuance Transform Rules'* correctly in the Web application Properties ( Application Groups -> MyApp -> MyApp - WebApplication -> Properties). However, it seems no matter what I do, **nothing seems to have any effect on the properties contained in the JWT returned from the endpoint**. I always get exactly the same token structure.

[image: Edit Rule Dialog]

I am not really sure how the 'Outgoing Claims' map to the token properties  as nothing except the 'UPN' and the 'unique name' seems to be transferred. Any pointers what I may be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

As indicated in nzpcmad's answer, it appears that custom claims in the id_token using the default URL-parameter-encoded GET redirect is simply not supported. The reason for this may be that there is an URL length limit, but I find that quite questionable.

Anyway, apparently this restriction does not apply when the token is returned in a POST redirect. That's also why people describe it working just fine for MVC applications.

So I was able to work around the problem by redirecting the response to a backend API endpoint (POST), which just redirects it to the frontend (SPA) again, but as a GET request with URL-endcoded parameters:

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login(FormDataCollection formData)
    {
        var token = formData["id_token"];
        var state = formData["state"];
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
        var frontendUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ad:FrontendUri"];
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri($"{frontendUri}#id_token={token}&state={state}");
        return response;
    }
}
```

Note that to change the response method from GET to POST, one simply has to add `&response_mode=form_post` to the OAuth request URL.

Comment: i got this working for initial token requests, but when it comes to renew requests, what did you do to handle?

Comment: Afaik there's no renewal-token contained in the token. To renew the token, just navigate to the login page again - you won't be prompted for credentials again, ADFS will recognize you using cookies (or so). I.e. ADFS has a "keep me signed in"-session, which stays active longer than the token lifetime. I think that is all configurable in ADFS. In our Single-Page-App I think we use a hidden iframe to go to the login page and getting the new token without reloading the page.

Comment: I was getting x-frame denied error.  This is coming from ADFS(im using 2019)
I fixed it by running  Set-AdfsResponseHeaders -RemoveHeaders "X-Frame-Options" on adfs server

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2016 is ADFS 4.0.

SPA uses OAuth implicit flow and there are a number of posts around this suggesting that this flow doesn't allow extra claims, especially if you are using ADAL.

e.g. [ADFS 4.0, Adal JS - No claims](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2ad07e3-957b-42a1-b63c-ef5e87a76422/adfs-40-adal-js-no-claims?forum=ADFS).

Comment: (edited) .. no, you're absolutely right about everything. Thanks! :)